What is purpose install-tools folder in installed gcc?
I installed GCC MinGW on my Linux machine and I don't understand how to using install-tools folder and it's purpose.
Typical path: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/install-tools
I saw online documentation and I didn't found information about it.
In general, How to use it?
